# How to delete some row in table1 and its change should reflect in table2 in C# using sql query?

Tags: c#, sql

Let us suppose I have two table namely Table1 and Table2.

Table1 contains:

```
+------+--------+  
| Name | Value  |    
+------+--------+  
| a    |      5 |   
| b    |     10 |   
| c    |      5 |   
| a    |     20 |   
| b    |     15 |   
+------+--------+
```

Table2 contains:

```
+------+--------+  
| Name | Value  |     
+------+--------+  
| a    |     25 |   
| b    |     25 |   
| c    |      5 |      
+------+--------+
```

My question is if i delete row 4 and row 5 in Table1 . The content of Table 2 should contain, somewhat like:

Table2:

```
+------+--------+  
| Name | Value  |     
+------+--------+  
| a    |     5  |   
| b    |     10 |   
| c    |     5  |      
+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trigger exemple which can do the work for you :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[up_update_my_second_table]
ON [dbo].[Table1] FOR DELETE
AS
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @Name = [Name] FROM deleted --deleted represents the deleted line.

UPDATE Table2 SET [Value] = 'YourValue' WHERE [Name] = @Name
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to store `table2` as a *table*, then you would need a trigger.  I would instead suggest that you use a view:

```
create view table1_summary as
    select t1.name, sum(t1.value) as value
    from table1 t1
    group by t1.name;
```

Then the values are calculated when you access the view.  Note:  This will be slower if `table1` is big.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Triggers in SQL to delete from Second  Table when you are trying to delete from First Table ..